# Looking for freehand editing tool in QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Is any tool in QGIS 3.x for freehand editing?

In 2.4 version it is there but in 3.x I can't find any tools.

Comment: There is a freehand editing plugin, but unfortunately it is available for QGIS 2.x.

Comment: If it's for lines, there is the [beePen](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/beePen/) plugin.